# how to copy conmanclient.exe and related files to the windows folder of device

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, ethernet

I need to debug a winCE application over the ethernet using Visual Studio 2005. I
have connected to the device over the ethernet and now need to run
conmanclient2.exe and cmaccept.exe before I can start debugging.
However, I don't know how to copy these files over the ethernet.
Please guide me.
Thankyou!

Comment: Are you building the Windows CE image?

Comment: yes I am. I was told that I needed to run these files before I could debug over the ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

You have a chicken-or-egg problem.  You can't copy the files over Ethernet unless you have some sort of connectivity, which is what those files provide.  You need to eitehr put them in the image, copy them using media (like a USB disk) or some other transport, if your device supports it, like FTP.  If you have networking, you might simply try browsing from the CE device to a network shared where you have the files located.